# how to work with array of hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
[[{"Postponed"=>10}], [{"Low"=>3}], [{"Medium"=>4}], [{"High"=>5}]]
```

is the array

how can I get the value corresponding to particular value.

say High returns 5 in this.
or how to convert this array of hashes to an array so that searching becomes easy.

I tried:

```
find_all { |v| v['name'] == "Low" }
```

but it says:

```
cant convert String to Integer
```

please provide some guidance

Comment: The best solution (IMHO) is to change how that structure gets created. Do you have the ability to do that?

Comment: yes Mark i have ability to do that, can you guide me through that?

Comment: Smells like a normal hash: `status = {"Postponed"=>10, "Low"=>3, "Medium"=>4, "High"=>5}`

Comment: yes normal hash.. how to convert that array oh hashes to normal hash?

Comment: Sure, but I recommend at this point you make another question about it. BTW, my answer below is a workaround that makes a single hash out of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have some code like:

```
array = [[{"Postponed"=>10}], [{"Low"=>3}], [{"Medium"=>4}], [{"High"=>5}]]
```

Then turn it into an ruby hash:

```
hash = array.inject({}) {|h, e| h.merge(e.first) }
# => {"Postponed"=>10, "Low"=>3, "Medium"=>4, "High"=>5}
```

So you can find 'Low' value easily :

```
hash['Low']
# => 3
```

EDIT: The answer of Mark Thomas is pretty great, and shorter than the inject since it does the same thing. He wrote it before I answered. Nice ;)

Answer (score 9):

How about making a single hash out of it for efficient querying?

```
arr.flatten.reduce(:merge)

#=> {"Postponed"=>10, "Low"=>3, "Medium"=>4, "High"=>5}
```

Comment: thnx Mark, ur answer was usefull :)

Answer (score 1):

In the general case, the hashes won't be unique, so you need to filter rather than pick one via indexing. For example, let's say you have this:

```
 arr = [[{:apple => 'abc'}], [{:banana => 'def'}], [{:coconut => 'ghi'}]]
 # => [[{:apple=>"abc"}], [{:banana=>"def"}], [{:coconut=>"ghi"}]]
```

Now let's suppose you want to get the value corresponding to any hash with a `:coconut` key. Then just use:

```
 arr.flatten.map { |h| h[:coconut] }.compact
 # => ["ghi"]
```

That gives you the list of answers. In this case there's only one matching key, so there's only one entry in the array. If there were other hashes that had a :coconut key in there, then you'd have something like:

```
 # => ["ghi", "jkl", "mno"]
```

On the whole, though, that's a very unusual data structure to have. If you control the structure, then you should consider using objects that can return you sensible answers in the manner that you'd like, not hashes.

Comment: well, thnx a lot @John.. it worked. can u also tell me how to change the structure of that. say in your example, i want to convert arr to some thing like this [{:apple => 'abc'}, {:banana => 'def'}].. i mean normal hash instead of array of hashes

Comment: Your example is still an array of hashes. (The original structure is an array of an array of hashes.) You can get what you just described with `arr.flatten`.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
  arr = [
    [{"Postponed"=>10}],
    [{"Low"=>3}], 
    [{"Medium"=>4}], 
    [{"High"=>5}]
  ]
  arr1 = []

  arr.each{|a|
    arr1.push(a[0])
  }
```

Although I wonder if you really just want to get one hash, which you'd do like so:

```
  myHash = {}

  arr.each{|a|
    a[0].each{|b, c|
      myHash[b] = c
    }
  }
```

You would then access it like `myHash["Postponed"]`

Comment: and then how got get value for key in arr1?

Comment: I realised that. I think you would be better off with a hash (see my subsequent edit). I only provided arr1 because you initially asked for an array.

Comment: thnx Simon for your quick response!

Answer (score 0):

You could simply call `#flatten` on the original array. That would give you an array of hashes. What I think you would really want is just one hash.

```
1.8.7 :006 > [[{"Postponed"=>10}], [{"Low"=>3}], [{"Medium"=>4}], [{"High"=>5}]].flatten
=> [{"Postponed"=>10}, {"Low"=>3}, {"Medium"=>4}, {"High"=>5}]
```

I would ask, what are you doing to get that original structure? Can that be changed?